# css jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

First apologize for my English. I have a popup when I do click in triggerPop this one it appears,
I'm trying to show this one to the right but the css doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

```
var monscreen = $(window).width();
var mondoc = $(document).width();

if (mondoc > monscreen) {
    var dif = mondoc - monscreen;
    $("div#Navigation_Popup").css({
        'right': dif + 'px'
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('#triggerPop').bind('click', function(e) {
        $("#Navigation_Popup").slideFadeToggle(function() {});
        return false;
    });

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, "fast", easing, callback);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Explain "doesn't work" (or show it). It's hard to give an answer if you don't know the exact problem.

Comment: Need html too, to solve this problem

Comment: What `position` is `#Navigation_Popup` set to?  It would require `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` for the `right` property to have any effect.

Comment: the position is absolute

Comment: div#Navigation_Popup {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align:left;
  position:absolute;
  width:394px;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border:1px solid black;
  color: #000;
  



}

Answer (score 1):

I'm going off of the limited information. You mentioned `css`...

I would move all of this code:

```
var monscreen = $(window).width();
var mondoc = $(document).width();

if (mondoc > monscreen) {
  var dif = mondoc - monscreen;
  $("div#Navigation_Popup").css({
    'right': dif + 'px'
  });
}
```

Inside of

```
$(function(){
  .
  .
  .
});
```

As it is now, the `if (mondoc > monscreen)` code block is getting executed before the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how jquery treat these values but, isnt var monscreen = $(window).width();
var mondoc = $(document).width(); returning strings? How about an alert to check this?

Comment: `-` will coerce them to numbers if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for his answers, I find my mistake :) the div, was inside an updatepanel and the ajax change the css

Answer (score 0):

Bind is deprecated, try on instead. I also think everything should be inside $(function()) handler, so, try this:

```
$(function() {
    var monscreen = $(window).width();
     var mondoc = $(document).width();

    if (mondoc > monscreen) {
        var dif = mondoc - monscreen;
        $("div#Navigation_Popup").css({
           'right': dif + 'px'
        });
    }
    $('#triggerPop').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#Navigation_Popup").slideFadeToggle(function() {});
        return false;
    });

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, "fast", easing, callback);
    }
});
```